# Show remaining time in video recorder in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, video-recording

I want to show remaining time on video recorder. Currently it is showing recording time. How can i?

My code is :

```
UIImagePickerController*  Videopicker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
Videopicker1.delegate = self;
Videopicker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
Videopicker1.showsCameraControls = YES;
Videopicker1.videoQuality=UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
Videopicker1.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]; // kUTTypeMovie is actually an NSString.
Videopicker1.videoMaximumDuration = 30.0f; // limits video length to 30 seconds.
[self presentModalViewController:Videopicker1 animated:YES];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nope.. finally leave it.

Answer (score 3):

On your VC.h file

```
@interface VideoCaptureVC_iPhone : UIViewController
<UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
    NSTimer *videoTimer;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *videoTimer;
```

On your vc.m file

```
- (void)pickerCameraSnap:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"start camera capture and timer");
    [picker startVideoCapture];
    self.videoTimer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(changeValue) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

make a calculation as per your need and change the text @"TimeRemaining" in proper place
i have rotated text for landscape view !

```
-(void)changeValue{
    UILabel *textNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 100)];
    textNameLabel.center = CGPointMake(30,285);
    textNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    textNameLabel.text = @"TimeRemaining";
    textNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    CGAffineTransform transformRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI  / 2));
    textNameLabel.transform = transformRotate;

    UIView *myOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    UIImage *overlayImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CameraOverlay"];
    UIImageView *overlayBg;
    overlayBg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:overlayImg];
    [myOverlay addSubview:overlayBg];
    [myOverlay addSubview:textNameLabel];
    [picker setCameraOverlayView:myOverlay];
}
```

and finally to stop the timer

```
- (void)stopCamera:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"stop camera");
    [self.videoTimer invalidate]; 

    [picker stopVideoCapture];
    [picker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have set a video maximum time, and you state you are currently showing the current duration.

```
TimeRemaining = videoMaximumDuration - currentDuration;
```

Comment: Where & How to show this time as video recorder showing on whole screen.

Comment: You could try adding a label and adding it to the video view or the root view.